# Identify webmail clients

Tags: email-analytics

I am developing a report for our emailing app and I need to identify which client email  opened emails sent. I searched and worked with user-agent and I find out if it is Firefox, Chrome or IE, but **I can not identify when it is Hotmail, Gmail, Yahoo** .... Please, I need your help.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If the emails contain images or other elements fetched from your server when opened, do the requests contain useful `referrer` information?  I wouldn't think so, but it's worth checking.

Comment: I dont think so (like you) but I will test. Thanks David.

Comment: Did you found a reliable solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable way of doing this.

Comment: Test Litmus and you will see it is possible!